# cdb and windbg unable to load MiniDumps, but VS 2008 loads them fine

Tags: windbg, crash-dumps, minidump

I am trying to build some automated crash dump analysis, but I cannot get cdb or windbg to load my crash dumps. They load just fine in VS 2008.

When I run dumpchk.exe on the file, I get:

```
Loading Dump File [c:\devx86\temp\ErrorDump.mdmp]
User Mini Dump File: Only registers, stack and portions of memory are available

ERROR: Memory range data only partially present in dump (RVA 0x1011F, size 0x94)
**** DebugClient cannot open DumpFile - error 80070570
DumpFile is corrupt
```

When I run cdb on the file, I get:

```
ERROR: Memory range data only partially present in dump (RVA 0x1011F, size 0x94)
Debuggee initialization failed, Win32 error 0n1392
    "The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable."
```

Answer (score 3):

Installing the latest version of the tools fixed the problem