# CDB is unable to load dump file but VS 2013 loads it fine

Tags: debugging, crash, windbg, crash-dumps, minidump

I have built an automated crash dump analysis, but I can't get CDB to load a specific crash dump.  It loads just fine in VS 2013.  I'm using the Debugger Tool from the Windows Driver Kits 8.1 (6.3.9600.16384) which seems to be the latest one.

When I run cdb.exe on the file, I get:

```
C:\Users\me>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x64\cdb.exe" -z "D:\DumpFiles\crashdump.mdmp"

Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.3.9600.16384 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Loading Dump File [D:\DumpFiles\crashdump.mdmp]
Dir entry 9, HandleDataStream stream header size exceeds stream size (0xff0000 > 0x485e0)
User Mini Dump File: Only registers, stack and portions of memory are available

ERROR: Memory range data only partially present in dump (RVA 0x1B64C, size 0xE740000)
Debuggee initialization failed, Win32 error 0n1392
    "Le fichier ou le r pertoire est endommag  et illisible."
```

The dump file size is 4,194,709 kb.

Output from dumpchk.exe

```
C:\Users\me>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x64\dumpchk.exe" "D:\DumpFiles\crashdump.mdmp"
Loading dump file D:\DumpFiles\crashdump.mdmp

Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.3.9600.16384 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [D:\DumpFiles\crashdump.mdmp]
Dir entry 9, HandleDataStream stream header size exceeds stream size (0xff0000 > 0x485e0)
User Mini Dump File: Only registers, stack and portions of memory are available

ERROR: Memory range data only partially present in dump (RVA 0x1B64C, size 0xE740000)
**** DebugClient cannot open DumpFile - error 80070570
DumpFile is corrupt
```

With cdb version 10:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.10075.9 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [D:\DumpFiles\crashdump.mdmp]
Dir entry 9, HandleDataStream stream header size exceeds stream size (0xff0000 > 0x485e0)
User Mini Dump File: Only registers, stack and portions of memory are available

ERROR: Memory range data only partially present in dump (RVA 0x1B64C, size 0xE740000)
Debuggee initialization failed, Win32 error 0n1392
Le fichier ou le r pertoire est endommag  et illisible.
```

But like I said, it loads really fine in Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491646/cdb-and-windbg-unable-to-load-minidumps-but-vs-2008-loads-them-fine). WinDbg Version 10 is newer ([WinDbg versions](http://debugging.wellisolutions.de/windbg-versions/))

Comment: With WinDbg there is `dumpchk` which can check dumps for corruption.